# Search List of Strings For String Match

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, search

I am trying to create a SQL trigger that will alert me when a user types in certain words. I have it working with a single word but I need to get this working with a list of words. How can I get something similar to the following, that will search a list of words stored in some other location.

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('BadWord',Body) > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a BadWords table and compare to the entries in that list in your trigger:

```
select
    *
from
    inserted i, badwords b
where
    charindex(b.badword, i.Body) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Join onto a bad word table

```
select
    *
from
    INSERTED I
    JOIN
    myBadWords B ON I.Body LIKE '%' + b.badword + '%'
```

This won't run well though because of the leading %. Full Text Search would be better

Comment: How can you do a full text search?

Comment: Also, to fire off my email would I need to put something after the 'LIKE' statement or elsewhere?